# ML.NET RandomizedPCA Trainer AUC not defined

Tags: c#, machine-learning, outliers, ml.net, anomaly-detection

First time learning how to use ML.NET
Wanted to try out Anomaly Detection on a Database.
I retrieve the following data:

```
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string CertValidFrom { get; set; }
    public string CertValidTo { get; set; }
    public float Label { get; set; }
```

Label is needed for the RandomizedPCATrainer and is set to 0.
I also featurized the text:

```
     IEstimator<ITransformer> dataProcessPipeline = mLContext.Transforms
         .Text.FeaturizeText("TitleF", "Title")
         .Append(mLContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("CertValidFromF", "CertValidFrom"))
         .Append(mLContext.Transforms.Text.FeaturizeText("CertValidToF", "CertValidTo"))
         .Append(mLContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "TitleF", "CertValidFromF", "CertValidToF"));
```

Then I used the following options:

```
      var options = new RandomizedPcaTrainer.Options {
          FeatureColumnName = "Features",
          ExampleWeightColumnName = null,
          Rank = 28,
          Oversampling = 20,
          EnsureZeroMean = true,
          Seed = 1};
```

But when evaluating the model with the testdata I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in Microsoft.ML.Core.dll: 'AUC is not defined when there is no positive class in the data'
```

I don't have a lot of experience so my question are:

- What does this error say?
- Is the dataProcessPipeline correct and what does it do?

Comment: How many rows of data are you using?

Comment: I am using 4000 rows at least. EDIT: I also tried with 60000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke so long story short, this algorithm did not fit my dataset, so I tried some different ones. So be aware to always research the uses cases of the algorithm you choose.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the label column values of your evaluted data ara all belong to same classfication.
So it throwed no positive class exeption and it can't evaute data without positive samples.(at least it can't calculate auc value)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).